# Interpolation of perturbed rotations and approximating the linearized effect of doubly perturbed rotations

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, perturbation-theory

I am reading through ["State Estimation for Robotics" by Timothy Barfoot](http://asrl.utias.utoronto.ca/%7Etdb/bib/barfoot_ser17.pdf) and I came across a line that I don't understand in pg 242, equation (7.136)

Suppose we have the following definitions:
$$
C = (C_2C_1^T)^{\alpha}C_1, \alpha \in [0,1]
$$

$$
C , C_1, C_2 \in SO(3),
$$
That is, we have a rotation matrix C that is an interpolation of two rotation matrices $C_2$ and $C_1$, with the interpolation parameter $\alpha$.
$$
C_{21} = \exp(\phi\text{^}) = C_2C_1^T,
$$
and
$$
C' , C_1', C_2' \in SO(3) 
$$
are perturbation rotation matrices for $C$, $C_1$, $C_2$ respectively with the left differences

$$
\delta\varphi = \ln(C'C^T)^{∨}
$$
$$
\delta\phi_1 = \ln(C_1'C_1^T)^{∨}
$$

$$
\delta\phi_2 = \ln(C_2'C_2^T)^{∨}.
$$
In finding a relationship between $\delta\varphi$ and $\delta\phi_1$ , $\delta\phi_2$, the author states that
\begin{align}
\exp(\delta\varphi\text{^})C \\
&= (\exp(\delta\phi_2\text{^})C_2C_1^T\exp(-\delta\phi_1\text{^}))^{\alpha}\exp(\delta\phi_1\text{^})C_1 \\
&\approx \exp((\phi + \textbf{J}(\phi)^{-1}(\delta\phi_2 - C_{21}\delta\phi_1))\text{^})^\alpha\exp(\delta\phi_1\text{^})C_1 \\
&\approx \exp((\alpha\phi + \alpha\textbf{J}(\phi)^{-1}(\delta\phi_2 - C_{21}\delta\phi_1))\text{^})\exp(\delta\phi_1\text{^})C_1
\end{align}
, which is straight forward to me.

However, what I don't understand is the following expression (continued):
$$\approx \exp((\alpha\textbf{J}(\alpha\phi)\textbf{J}(\phi)^{-1}(\delta\phi_2-C_{21}\delta\phi_1))\text{^})C_{21}^{\alpha}$$

While trying to understand this, I was thinking I could understand it along the line of:

$$\delta\phi_3 = \delta\phi_2 - C_{21}\delta\phi_1$$
$$\phi_3 = \alpha\phi$$
and
$$\alpha\textbf{J}^{-1}(\phi)$$
$$=\textbf{J}^{-1}(\alpha\phi)$$
$$=\textbf{J}^{-1}(\phi_3)$$
due to the linear operator property of Jacobian so that
the last expression is expressive of something like $\exp(\phi_3 + J(\phi)^{-1}\delta\phi_3)\text{^}) \approx \exp(\delta\phi_3\text{^})\exp(\phi_3\text{^}))$, but I don't think it quite matches up with the final expression..
Also, I am not sure where the $\textbf{J}(\alpha\phi)$ is coming from.

Could someone please explain to me how this line is derived? This book is my first encounter with Lie Algebra.

Much thanks in advance.